# I am not able to pass my recent values added in service method to html page

Tags: angularjs, html

This is my first html page where I need to populate my recently added data:

```
<div>
<!--I have binded busdomain through controller -->
 <swt-tree tree-data="busdomain"</swt-tree>
</div>
```

This is my child html page which is called under first page and I want to pass the values entered on this page to my parent page. But not getting recent values until I reload the page.

```
<span ng-show="true"</span>Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
 <input focus="" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="busdomain.name" ng-change="domainNameChanged()" required="true">   
  </div>
<button  type="submit" ng-click="addSubTree(createdomain.$valid)" id="btnData">OK</button>
```

This is my controller, I have called service through controller:

```
controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) {  
    $scope.activeTab = 1;
    $scope.currentBDStatement=[];
    $scope.statements=[];
    $scope.childBD =[];
    $scope.busdomain=[];
<!--It is used when I navigate from parent to child for the first time -->
    $scope.busdomain = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
    $scope.addSubTree = function(val){          
            //Done some code here
//In $scope.statements I am getting the values which I need to pass on html page
//I am setting the value in service which I got from my child html page
            DomainNameService.setBusDomain($scope.statements);
//Here I am calling the get method of my service and able to get the values which i have set.
            $scope.busdomain = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
//Redirecting to my parent page here I want to show the values which i have set in $scope.busdomain but I am not getting recent added values..
            $state.go('BusDomainTree');

        }
```

This is my service.js:

Here I have used getter and setter:

```
app.factory('DomainNameService', function() {
var busDomain = undefined;
var busDomainValue=[];
setBusDomain:function(busDomName){
        this.busDomainValue=busDomName;
    },
 getBusDomainName: function(){
<!--I am getting the values here which I need to pass to html page -->
        return this.busDomainValue;
    }
})
```

Full controller code:

```
 controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) {  
        $scope.activeTab = 1;
        $scope.currentDomain = {};
        $scope.currentBDStatement=[];
        $scope.statements=[];
        $scope.childBD =[];
        var statementTree = {};
        $scope.busdomain=[];
        $scope.domain = DomainNameService.getDomainName();//Getting parent name here
        $scope.busdomain = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
        //$scope.busDom = DomainNameService.getBusDomainModel($scope.statements);
        $scope.addTree = function(isValid) {
                if(isValid) {
        var stType = $scope.domain.name;//Getting value from html page of parent
                $scope.currentDomain = $scope.getNewDomain(stType,varType);
                $scope.statements.push($scope.currentDomain);
        //Adding parent name to tree code       $scope.statementTree.setNewInput($scope.statements);
                $scope.isAdd = false;
                DomainNameService.addDomain($scope.domain.name);
                $scope.domain.domainName = DomainNameService.getDomainName()[0];
                $state.go('DomainTree');
                }
            }

            $scope.getNewDomain = function(stType,varType) {
                //passing parent name as json
                return {domainNode:[{name:stType}],name:stType, varName:varType};   
            }

            $scope.addbusinessDomain = function() {
                $state.go('DomainTree.businessDomain');
            }
            //This method is called for child   
            $scope.addSubTree = function(val){
                var varType = "busDomain";
                var domain=[];
                var busDomainName=$scope.busdomain.name;
                var parent = DomainNameService.getDomainName()[0];
                DomainNameService.addChildBD(busDomainName);
                $scope.childBD=DomainNameService.getChildBD();
                $scope.currentStatement = $scope.busdomain.name;
            $scope.currentBDStatement.push($scope.busdomain.name);    $scope.currentDomainName=$scope.getBusDomain($scope.childBD,parent,varType);
                $scope.statements.push($scope.currentDomainName);
            $scope.statementTree.setNewInput($scope.statements);
DomainNameService.setBusDomain($scope.statements);
                $scope.busdomain = DomainNameService.getBusDomainName();
                $state.go('BusDomainTree');
            }
        $scope.getBusDomain = function(stType,parent,varType) {
            return {node:[{name:parent}],name:parent, childNode:stType, refType: varType};
        }
```

I am able to fetch values from service but I am not able to populate the recently added value to html page. For that I need to reload the page. Please some one help me out in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried simply adding it to the page? Can you rephrase the problem?

Comment: I have one parent html page on which I am calling my child page. I want to show the values which I got from child page to parent page in a tree like structure. I am able to get the values from child page in controller and able to set and get that values from service also. But I am not able to see the value on my parent page which I have entered recently. For that I need to reload the page. Can you please suggest a solution for this

Comment: You could look into $broadcast and $on

Comment: I agree with `Guinn`, we have to use $broadcast and $on. And controller will execute at first time of you(Fatema Rangwala) called. So if we update data in service, the service data won't collect in controller.

Comment: Please add code parent controller & child. `domainController` is parent?

Comment: I am using common controller for parent and child, using different methods in this controller. I am passing my parent name to child method (addSubTree())and adding it's child in this method.

Comment: Can anyone please give a example of how to use $broadcast and $on in my code. Have gone through some of the examples but didn't got the exact way of implementing it.

Comment: You can try implement & understanding `$broadcast` and `$on` further from, for example, this external [tutorial: Understanding Angular’s $scope and $rootScope event system $emit, $broadcast and $on](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/). Give it a shot!

Comment: thank you all. I just want to confirm one thing should i use different controller or using different method in same controller is fine.

Comment: I got a solution for this thank you all for help: I used $state.go('BusDomainTree', null, { reload: true });